# Foreach issue in get_posts function

Tags: posts, categories

My category is coming from comma separated place and then i put it into get_posts's args array, but my query gives me only last category's posts. Please have a look at my code below:

```
$content_arr = explode(",", $content);

  if ( is_array($content_arr) && count($content_arr) > 0 ) {
    foreach ($content_arr as $category_name) { // Category loop
      $args = array(
        'category_name'  => trim($category_name),
        'posts_per_page' => 7,
        'order'          => 'DESC',
        'orderby'        => 'post_date',
      );

      $output = '';      
      // $posts = get_posts($args);
      $post_counter = 1;

      $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

      if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : 
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); 
            if ( has_post_thumbnail() ):
              //the_post_thumbnail();
            else: 

            endif;
            $output .= '<div class="col-md-4 mb-5">'.get_the_ID().'-'.get_the_title().'</div>';
            $post_counter++;
        endwhile; 
        $the_query->reset_postdata();
        echo $post_counter."-";
      endif;
```

In $content_arr have 3 category as array element so first foreach is running 3 times but my output is showing only one category posts.
Somehow it is resetting my previous category's results.
How can i show my all categories posts one by one?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that in the beginning of each loop you reset `$output` to an empty string:

```
$output = '';
```

So when then loop has finished, `$output` will only contain the output of the last loop.

To fix the issue you'll just need to move this line outside of the loop, to initialise the variable, while only adding to it with `.=` inside the loop:

```
$content_arr = explode( ',', $content);
$output      = '';

if ( is_array( $content_arr ) && count( $content_arr ) > 0 ) {
    foreach ( $content_arr as $category_name ) {
        $args = array(
            'category_name'  => trim( $category_name ),
            'posts_per_page' => 7,
            'order'          => 'DESC',
            'orderby'        => 'post_date',
        );

        $post_counter = 1;
        $the_query    = new WP_Query( $args );

        if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : 
            while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); 
                if ( has_post_thumbnail() ):
                    //the_post_thumbnail();
                else: 

                endif;

                $output .= '<div class="col-md-4 mb-5">' . get_the_ID() . '-' . get_the_title() . '</div>';

                $post_counter++;
            endwhile;

            $the_query->reset_postdata();

            echo $post_counter . "-";
        endif;
```

Comment: Yes you are correct.